# Class Properties not declared

Tags: python, class, oop

How can this code work, when some of the Class Properties were not declared  ?

Class A was declared with only one property aa
but it was possible to "Assign" other properties to Object A which were stored in List L and could be referenced later.

```
class A(object):
     aa = ''

L = []

One = A()
L.append(One)

One.Type = 'One_Type'
One.Name = 'One'
One.Top = 200
One.Left = 50

Two = A()
L.append(Two)

Two.Type = 'Two_Type'
Two.Name = 'Two'
Two.Text = 'Hello'

One.XXX = 'XXX'

for i in range(len(L)):  
    for key, value in L[i].__dict__.items():
        print(L[i].Name, key, value)#, L[i].Type)
    print    
print
```

And this is the result:

```
('One', 'Top', 200)
('One', 'XXX', 'XXX')
('One', 'Type', 'One_Type')
('One', 'Name', 'One')
('One', 'Left', 50)

('Two', 'Text', 'Hello')
('Two', 'Type', 'Two_Type')
('Two', 'Name', 'Two')
```

Comment: Python is dynamic, you can assign any attribute you like to your custom classes at runtime (unless you're using e.g. `__slots__`, have subclassed `namedtuple`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to limit the number of properties available for a given class' members, use `__slots__` in class definition. Consider this example in python interactive shell:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     __slots__ = ('some', 'other')
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.some = 1
...         self.other = 2
>>> a = A()
>>> a.some
1
>>> a.some = 2
>>> a.some
2
>>> a.third = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<bpython-input-13>", line 2, in <module>
    a.third = 3
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'third'
```

But indeed usually a pythonish approach to object properties is completely dynamic: if a particular instance needs a specific unique property or a method, it's nothing wrong to assign it.